# How to test event registration in Rhino Mocks

Tags: events, rhino-mocks

I am trying to write a Rhino Mocks test to verify that I have registered for an event. Here is my test:

```
   var dataSvc = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDataService>();
   Search srch = new Search(dataSvc, vr); 
   dataSvc.GetCarriersCompleted += srch.OnCarrierDataReturned;
   dataSvc.AssertWasCalled(x => x.GetCarriersCompleted += Arg<GetCarriersCompletedEventArgs>.Is.Anything);
```

My code is just a simple register for event like this:

```
    public void GetCarrierList()
    {
        try
        {
            _dataService.GetCarriersCompleted += OnCarrierDataReturned; ; //hangedEventHandler(OnDataReturned);
            _dataService.GetCarriersAsync(_param);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void OnCarrierDataReturned(object sender, GetCarriersCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       // get results
    }
```

My data service looks like this:

```
    void GetCarriersAsync(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> param);
    event System.EventHandler<GetCarriersCompletedEventArgs> GetCarriersCompleted;
```

I can't figure out what Rhino Mocks needs for this test. The error is:

Error   7   Cannot implicitly convert type 'MACS2SLApp.MACSWcfServiceProxy.GetCarriersCompletedEventArgs' to 'System.EventHandler'    C:\Documents and Settings\600124238\My Documents\MACS3\Prototype\Web UI\MACSUnitTests\MACSUnitTests.cs  126 68  MACSUnitTests

Any ideas would be appreciated.

thanks,
Bill44077

Comment: Am I on the right track here or way off base? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Arg<>` constraint needs to be the type of event, not the type of event args.  Try:

```
Arg<EventHandler<GetCarriersCompletedEventArgs>>.Is.Anything
```